# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'waitkey'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')

cv2.imshow('result',image)

cv2.waitkey(0)
```

--error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Ahmed Sabry\Desktop\finding-lanes\lanes.py", line 5, in <module>

    cv2.waitkey(0)

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'waitkey'
```

Comment: `cv2.waitKey()` the `k` is uppercase

Comment: in code you have uppercas `K` in `waitKey` but error shows lowercase `k` in waitkey. Maybe you edit code in one file but you run code from different file.

Comment: @furas no, OP just had it as `waitkey` (hence the error), and they tried to correct it after the comment (but only in the code, and not in the error message) - see edit history.

Comment: @desertnaut few times I already saw question where someone was running different file with different code and error didn't fit to code - and this is why I wrote it in comment.

Comment: @furas of course - I just answered to inform you that this is not the case here :)

Comment: @desertnaut frankly, this question is 2 months old and I forgot it long time ago :). Sometimes I visit so many questions that I don't remeber questions from previous hour :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are using 'k' in your waitkey , which is inlower case it should be in upper case as

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: still same error

Comment: I am able to replicate your error by using 'cv2.waitkey(0)' and no error by using 'cv2.waitKey(0)' , please check again there might some mistakes

Comment: there is no error but the pic not opened

Comment: Show and then disappear in second